# Magnific Popup Conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

I have a JS conflict occurring and cannot figure it out.

My site is a one page layout that uses smooth scroll to move from section to section.

There are 4 scripts in particular that I believe are conflicting.

The problem is once I click an image to open it, the page bounces right back to the top instead of staying where it is. After closing the image popup, I have to scroll back down every time. You will also notice that after closing the popup image, clicking any nav button at the top forces a scroll from the top down and not from the current position (as shown earlier in the video).

This problem is even worse in Safari (Firefox does not do this part) as the active nav items do not display (green highlight) after closing a popup image.

Please have a look at a video screen grab I posted of the issue I am having.

http://whataprettyface.ca/video2.html

I have the Filterizr / Magnific Popup / Portfolio working perfectly on my mobile site. But the mobile site does not include the smooth scroll feature.

As mentioned above, I am using:

1) Magnific Popup v1.1.0 (Pops open images in forefront)

http://whataprettyface.ca/desktop/js/jquery.magnific-popup.js

2) J.Query Filterizr (arranges selected photo gallery)

http://whataprettyface.ca/desktop/js/jquery.filterizr.js

3) My 'Scripts' main JS (contain smooth scroll code)

http://whataprettyface.ca/desktop/js/scripts.js

4) And a 'portfolio" script:

```
 $(function(){
'use strict';

 // portfolio filter container
$('.filtr-container').filterizr('filter', '1');

// portfolio filter
$('.simplefilter li').click(function() {
    $('.simplefilter li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});

// portfolio image-popup
$(".image-popup").magnificPopup({
    type: "image",
    removalDelay: 300,
    mainClass: "mfp-fade"
});

});
```

I have read about no.Conflict but am not sure how to properly implement it here or if it will even work.

I feel like the answer is before my eyes but I am a novice.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Okay so I tried  this on my phone (iPhone) and the issue was non existent. I then set the user agent on my laptop safari to iPad and the issue was also non existent.

So the problem (somehow) is only occurring on desktop browsers....

Answer (score 0):

To my dismay, the issue was not in my scripts at all. It was as simple as changing a few lines in my CSS.

By moving the 'hidden overflow' from the html/body and adding in to the portfolio container, the issue was resolved.

```
#work .container{
    overflow: hidden;
}
```